# Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(scripts) when adding external js to a non-application project

Tags: javascript, angular, jqbootstrapvalidation

Already updated my node and angular. When doing **ng build** I get error:
Schema validation failed with the following errors:

> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(scripts).

generated project via:

```
ng n my-proj **-create-application=false**
```

angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-proj-lib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/my-proj-lib",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/my-proj-lib/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/my-proj-lib/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "scripts": [
              "other-libs/jqBootstrapValidation.js"
            ],
            "project": "projects/my-proj-lib/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          ...
        },
        "lint": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "my-proj-lib"
}
```